# JQuery array sum of comma separated values

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

The following is data in array **(id,num1,num2,qty)**.

```
1,500,1000,1
2,700,1200,1
3,900,1400,1
```

How do I sum and display the following data?

```
500 + 700 + 900
1000 + 1200 + 1400
```

> Result
>   2100
>   3600

This is what I have so far...

```
var allItems = [];

function calcWattage() {
 allItems = [];
 $(".cbx").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
      allItems.push(this.id + "," + ($(this).val()) + "<br />");
 });
 $("#result").html(allItems.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like

```js
var array = [
  [1, 500, 1000, 1],
  [2, 700, 1200, 1],
  [3, 900, 1400, 1]
];

var result = array.reduce(function(value, array) {
  value[0] += array[1];
  value[1] += array[2];
  return value;
}, [0, 0]);
console.log(result)
```